# unable to find source package for llvm-3.3

Tags: llvm, apt-get, ubuntu-11.10

i am getting the following error while running `sudo apt-get build-dep llvm-3.3`

```
unable to find source package for llvm-3.3
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (i am using this old version for a special purpose) i am trying to build a particular software and their build instruction ask to use ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

LLVM 3.3 was never released for Ubuntu 11.10 so you will not be able to find the package in the source archives.

You can downloaded LLVM 3.3 directly from the LLVM [site](http://llvm.org/releases/) and manually do the configure,make,install process to configure it on your system. You may need to manually hunt down some dependencies for this to work but ./configure will tell you what you need.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Micheal , What i need to do is to just install all the dependencies of llvm -3.3 , but to install llvm-3.3. Still i am confused why the Build instruction of that software asked to select Ubuntu-11.10 and to run sudo apt-get build-dep llvm-3.3 on that!!!

Comment: Can you send me a link to the instructions? I may be able to figure out whether it's a misunderstanding or bad instructions. 

Those instructions would work fine on Ubuntu 12.04 so that could be the cause of confusion.

If they are in house instructions try and track down the person that wrote them. If they are no longer there, remember your frustration just and try to write documentation so as not to put anyone else in the same position :)

Comment: Okey... [this](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/sonar/projects/symdrive/downloads.shtml) is what i am trying....under the title Setting "up the Environment and S2E" they says the version of ubuntu. and  [this](http://reproducibility.cs.arizona.edu/v2/data/osdi12_renzelmann2012symdrive_build.txt) is the build setting by the developer that i'm following.

Comment: Having a look through the notes it looks like the developer used Ubuntu 12.04: `2:BUILD_ENVIRONMENT[operating system 32 vs 64] Ubuntu 12.04.5 64-bit`

Can you speak to your colleagues and see if you can use 12.04 instead, it will be a lot less painful! I would expect those instructions to run without an issue on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.10 is not longer supported, it may be that you are not getting any packages from the repositories.

Change your `/etc/sources.list` to the following:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
```

And then run `apt-get update` and then try again.

There is an article [here](https://coderwall.com/p/3n6xka/fix-apt-on-old-unsupported-ubuntu-releases) with more detail.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what the issue is then. Can you try `apt-get source llvm-toolchain-3.3`

This is the package that is downloaded when I try this in 12.04

Comment: tried that also.. but shows the same error "unable to find a source package for llvmut-toolchain-3.3". But it is working fine with llvm-2.9. i need atleast llvm-3.0

Comment: OK, a little bit more digging shows that 3.3 was never delivered with Oneric, it will not be in the source archives.

You can download the source directly from llvm [here](http://llvm.org/releases/) and do "configure,make,install" instead of using the package repositories.

Or you could try adding repositories from Ubuntu 12.04 to your `/etc/apt/sources.lst`, it may all work together but could cause headaches.